# Adding a grid to an R bwplot

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to add a horizontal grid to a bwplot. My original plot is done with

```
bwplot(values~ind, prices,ylim=c(0,110))
```

That's coming out fine (except no grid, of course). From the documentation I see an example using `panel.grid`, although it looks like a magical incantation because I don't really know R that well. I try to adapt the example and enter:

```
bwplot(values~ind, prices,
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.grid(h=-1, v = 0)
       }, ylim=c(0,110))
```

Well, that gives me the grid, true, but I no longer see my data!

So what am I doing wrong (and is there any R documentation out there that covers this sort of thing and *isn't* for gurus?)

Answer (score 2):

You should call `panel.bwplot` also within your panel function:

```
bwplot(values~ind, prices,
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.grid(h=-1, v = 0)
         panel.bwplot(...)
       }, ylim=c(0,110))
```

Another option is to `latticeExtra` like :

```
library(latticeExtra)
bwplot(values~ind, prices,axis=axis.grid)
```